# facebook share and facebook links not showing proper count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share

facebook like and facebook count on the page is showing random counts. Also in facebook share, incorrect url is shown while sharing. But after sharing sometimes it works fine. Is it because of the app_id created and used in dev box and we used the same app_id in production as well.

Comment: You're better off asking this over at http://developers.facebook.com.

Answer (score 0):

On my blog, I found that it helps to run the URL for a post through the Facebook Linter / Debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to ensure that Facebook will strip out the correct open graph meta data. See if that gives you the correct URL and other information.

I'm having the same problem with Like buttons displaying the wrong count.